# Concatenate some value(s) to a vararg parameter array

Tags: generics, compiler-errors, kotlin, variadic-functions

I've been trying to fill in the gap (`val args = ...`) in the below function. Tried everything I could think of and found a pretty convoluted solution. I have a feeling there's a better way, **please suggest a more Kotlin-y way. Am I missing a concept/operator/fun/type?**

```
class Result
interface Runner { fun execute(vararg tasks: String): Result }

fun Runner.debugExec(vararg tasks: String): Result {
// red: compile errors, mostly 
    //val args = tasks + "--debug" 
    //val args: Array<String> = tasks + "--debug"
    //val args: Array<out String> = tasks + "--debug"
    //val args = tasks + arrayOf("--debug")
    //val args = tasks + arrayOf<String>("--debug")
    //val args = tasks + listOf("--debug")
    //val args = tasks + (arrayOf("--debug") as Array<out String>)
    //val args = tasks + arrayOf<out String>("--debug") // Projections are not allowed here
    //val args = tasks.toList() + "--debug" // spread operator doesn't work
    //val args = tasks.plusElement("--debug") // cannot infer
    //val args = "--debug" + tasks // it's .toString() and spread operator doesn't work
// yellow: works, but warns
    //val args = (tasks as Array<String>) + "--debug" // unchecked cast
// green: but we must be able to do better, it's kotlin after all! 
    //val args = (tasks.toList() + "--debug").toTypedArray() // too many method calls
    println(args)
    return this.execute(*args)
}
```

The compile error I get most of the time is something like:

```
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.
Array<T>.plus(T)
  where T cannot be inferred for
    operator fun <T> Array<T>.plus(element: T): Array<T> defined in kotlin.collections
Array<out String>.plus(Array<out String>)
  where T = CapturedTypeConstructor(out String) for
    operator fun <T> Array<T>.plus(elements: Array<out T>): Array<T> defined in kotlin.collections
Array<out String>.plus(Collection<String>)
  where T = CapturedTypeConstructor(out String) for
    operator fun <T> Array<T>.plus(elements: Collection<T>): Array<T> defined in kotlin.collections
```

Note: `return this.execute(*tasks, "--debug")` would work, if there was no printing, and/or code duplication would be acceptable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aha! Found one "better" solution, though it's not using `+`:

```
val args = arrayOf(*tasks, "--debug")
```

Answer (score 3):

That's a generics problem. Arrays in Kotlin are invariant, which isn't the case for Java e.g.

The docs say:

> ```
> fun <T> asList(vararg ts: T)
> ```
>
> "Inside a function a `vararg`-parameter of type `T` is visible as an array of `T`, i.e. the ts variable in the example above has type `Array<out T>`."

An `Array<out T>` can only function as a producer of `T`, it's not possible to **add** elements. The operators that `+` maps to, are only defined on `Array<T>`, i.e. without the `out` modifier.

You can make the method accept `tasks: Array<String>` instead, which does not use any projections and allows the array to be used as a consumer, too.

Comment: In my reading I'm trying to use `tasks` that way, so it "produces" all the values from passed-in array as a basis of a new array to which there's a new element added. Arrays are immutable, so `.plus` is not really adding, is it?

Comment: Of course, but the operator is defined on `Array<T>`, without `out` modifier.  This one works as well:     val args = tasks.asList().toTypedArray()  + "--debug"

Comment: Thanks for the leading thought: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48454445/253468

Answer (score 0):

[s1m0nw1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8073652/s1m0nw1)'s clarifying [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48454253/concatenate-to-vararg-parameter-using/48454405#comment83901746_48454329) made me check the declaration again and I noticed that the param is `<out T>`:

```
public operator fun <T> Array<T>.plus(elements: Array<out T>): Array<T>
```

that could be useful:

```
val args =  arrayOf("--debug") + tasks
```

It forces the custom part to be in front, which works in my case, but may not in general.